How is the live session created?
What is special to the Ubuntu live session, compared to a normal user session, besides the non-persistence? How is this session created? What changes happen on top of a regular user that would copy files from /etc/skel?

Are you using the terminal page (https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Terminal-Page) when you add the files? Try creating the directory first ( mkdir -p /etc/skel/Desktop)

I don't know what I was doing wrong before, but putting files on /etc/skel/Desktop does get them shown on the Desktop of the live session. But my question still remains on how this special session is created. For example, where is it specified that the installer .desktop should appear on the Desktop?

I edited my question to make it more about the procedure and less about my customization struggles.

The live session in the boot stage needs a hook for initramfs-tools that will generate an initramfs capable of booting live systems as those created by casper or live-boot. At boot time this hook will look for a read-only media in a directory like /casper or /live where a root filesystem (*.squashfs) is stored. If found, it will create a writable environment, using an overlay (as in Casper case), for Debian-like systems to boot from, or create a writable environment, using aufs, to boot the system from (as in live-boot case).


There is a kernel parameter like BOOT=casper or BOOT=live and options like persistent, toram, and others can be added to the kernel line in the boot menu entry. for more details about that, you can see casper manupage and live-boot manupage


The configuration file /etc/casper.conf is used to change some variables:
# This file should go in /etc/casper.conf
# Supported variables are:
# USERNAME, USERFULLNAME, HOST, BUILD_SYSTEM, FLAVOUR

export USERNAME="ubuntu"
export USERFULLNAME="Live session user"
export HOST="ubuntu"
export BUILD_SYSTEM="Ubuntu"

# USERNAME and HOSTNAME as specified above won't be honoured and will be set to
# flavour string acquired at boot time, unless you set FLAVOUR to any
# non-empty string.

# export FLAVOUR="Ubuntu"


`live-boot` configuration files:
/etc/live/boot.conf
/etc/live/boot/*
live/boot.conf
live/boot/*
persistence.conf


You can add a user to the system before exiting the `chroot` environment, this will generate the user directories in the `/home` so you can add a `*.desktop` in any directory of them.
adduser username
adduser username sudo
adduser username adm


where is it specified that the installer .desktop should appear on the
Desktop?

The installer .desktop path is /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap_ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap.desktop in the file /casper/minimal.standard.live.squashfs. One of the options in the kernel line in the menu entry is layerfs-pathe=minimal.standard.live.squashfs
menuentry "Try or Install ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64" {
     
loopback loop /ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper layerfs-path=minimal.standard.live.squashfs iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash locale=en_US bootkbd=us console-setup/layoutcode=us noeject --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}

